# How to change the directory CTest runs from in generated Visual Studio Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cmake, ctest

I am currently having trouble changing the directory CTest in when using the RUN_TESTS project generated by CMake.  Currently CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is set to a custom path.  As a result when CTest attempts to run, it is doing so from a directory that contains no binaries.

As a temporary workaround I am calling ADD_TEST using ${RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}\test but I am not sure if this is the correct solution.  Is there a way a better way change the default directory used by CTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ADD_EXECUTABLE target is say `my_exe` and your test name `my_test`, you should be able to call `ADD_TEST` like:

```
ADD_TEST(NAME my_test COMMAND my_exe)
```

For further info, run

```
cmake --help-command ADD_TEST
```